# Does PowerBI directly connect with Azure's ML workbench?

Tags: azure, powerbi

Does PowerBI directly connect with Azure's ML workbench?

if yes,How?

Please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Azure ML Workbench is compute tool for building and executing Data Science experiments and analytics, it is not a data store. ML Workbench would typically have data store inputs and outputs (e.g. SQL Server or Azure Data Lake). You would connect PowerBI on to the output (or input if you need) data set in order to visualise the analytics produced in the ML Workbench.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1) I would like to know which is the best one in real time either workbench or ML studio in the prespective of Marketing sales product(Business Intelligence) for visualization and forecasting prediction. 2) please share link if any for workbench integration with power bi.3)which is the best language we can choose for Data analysis either R or Python(because Power Bi doesn't support python)

Comment: Those are all very subjective questions. Choosing the right language depends on what you are trying to achieve and the skills you already have. Real time analytics is better served through HD Insight and Spark or Stream Analytics.  Sounds like you need to figure out an end to end architecture - look at the lambda architecture as a start point.